# "gem update --system is disabled on Debian" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I try to update rubygems (by running 'gem update --system') I get this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
gem update --system is disabled on Debian. RubyGems can be updated using the official Debian repositories by aptitude or apt-get.
```

Any idea what might be wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways: get rid of the debian ruby package and install ruby from source, or you can follow the instrucions given to you:

> RubyGems can be updated using the official Debian repositories by aptitude or apt-get.

the rubygems with debian is managed by apt, and so you need to update it with it. If you don't want to, you need to install ruby on you own, without using apt. Or at least you need to install ruby-gems on you own. Try this:

```
[sudo] apt-get remove rubygems
wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.3.7.tgz
tar xzf rubygems-1.3.7.tgz
cd rubygems-1.3.7
[sudo] ruby setup.rb
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the way to go for me. I have a few rails apps I'm working on, how will they be affected by this?

Comment: It's possible that you need to reinstall all required gems, but other than this, there shouldn't be any side effects.

Comment: Even in 2014 as well :)

Comment: Debian will not change that policy. If you install rubygems from a debian package, it really _shouldn't_ allow rubygems to overwrite files installed by the debian package. Expect it to stay that way even though it's 2015

Answer (score 1):

Just from reading the error message, I'd suggest updating RubyGems via apt (`sudo apt-get install rubygems`) instead of from within RubyGems.

Comment: Just tried that but I seem to have the same version of rubygems as before (1.3.5)

Comment: That's probably because debian hasn't update rubygems yet. Debian is known to be very thorough before going to a new version of a package. You can try install it manually like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## in debian wheezy

- remove rubygems

  #### apt-get remove rubygems
- get a source

  #### wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.8.7.tgz
- uncompress source

  #### tar zxvf rubygems-1.8.7.tgz
- move directory

  #### cd rubygems-1.8.7
- run setup.rb with ruby

  #### ruby setup.rb
- update system

  #### gem update --system

then it'll installing newest versionand

Comment: It will install ruby gems as `gem1.8` not `gem` and `gem update --system` will simply update the gem you just installed to latest, not what you want. To link you have to do this: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/bin/gem`