# Invalid gemspec (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have successfully installed ruby on rails on Linux raspberrypi 3.10.25+. Ruby version is ruby 1.9.3p194. I imported a ruby on rails based project from github (https://github.com/iobridge/thingspeak). Using the command line I went into project's directory and ran "bundle install" and got the following error. Please note that not even a single bundle was installed.

```
Installing rake 10.3.1
Invalid gemspec in [/tmp/bundler20140528-7444-ym92r7/ZenTest-4.9.5/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.5.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]
Installing ZenTest 4.9.5
Using i18n 0.6.9
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.5.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]
Installing minitest 4.7.5
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.5.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]
```

The same error was shown for all the bundles.

How do I fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/issues/29). Upgrade your RubyGems and remove and install again the `ZenTest` gem:

```
gem update --system
gem uninstall ZenTest
gem install ZenTest
```

Comment: I ran gem update --system and got this error - Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.5.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/specifications/ZenTest-4.10.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in subtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through apt-get,using Debian official repositories

Comment: That's an entirely different issue. See this for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643870/gem-update-system-is-disabled-on-debian-error

Comment: Get rbenv or rvm installed and get out of your systems Ruby. I use Debian and it's sources alway lag until testing is approved for releases.

Comment: Got timed out for edits again. Debian system will keep Ruby and use packages it needs for new software that depends on Ruby. Let them handle that and get your own development environment set up. That's why these version control packages for user not root.