# Installing a gem from a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I want to use transpec to try and convert my specs to rspec 3:

```
https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec
```

But I cannot access the gem through a firewall.

I downloaded the transpec project, is there a way I can install this gem from the project?  I don't want to include it in a gem file as I will only be using it once.

Is there a way to do something like?

`gem install <path to project>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Gemfile

```
gem 'transpec', path: 'path/to/your/gem'
```

This has worked for me.

I usually dump them in vendor/gems, so:

```
gem 'transpec', path: 'vendor/gems/transpec'
```

After you're done you can remove vendor/gems/transpec and remove it from your Gemfile

Comment: There was a Errno::ENOENT while loading transpec.gemspec:
No such file or directory - git ls-files -z from
  D:/Rails/transpec-master/transpec.gemspec:18:in ``'

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use your Gemfile, you can download, build, and install from your command line:

```
git clone https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec.git

cd transpec && gem build transpec.gemspec

sudo gem install transpec-3.0.5.gem #or whatever version it may be
```

Comment: Not absolutely necessary. I just included it because some people may need it.

Comment: Recommending use a `sudo` command like that, could lead people to make huge mistakes. –

Comment: D:\Rails\transpec-master>gem build transpec.gemspec
Invalid gemspec in [transpec.gemspec]: No such file or directory - git ls-files
-z
ERROR:  Error loading gemspec. Aborting.

Comment: Upgrade your RubyGems and try again. Apparently this is a known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905870/invalid-gemspec-ruby-on-rails